# how to set a Viewmodel property when a listbox item is selected

Tags: properties, listbox, set, viewmodel, selecteditem

I'm creating a spline designer which requires multiple spline parts.
It contains 2 views (2 UserControls).

The left one is an ItemsControl templated as a Canvas displaying the splines to edit.
The splines parts are UserControls as well.

The right one is a simple ListBox used to select a Spline part.

These two item container are bound to the same ObservableCollection in a ViewModel.

For now, I have a dependencyProperty in the SplinePartVM named IsSelected 
What I exactly want to achieve is to modify the DependencyProperty of the SplinePartVM when the SelectedItem is set in the ListBox.
for example, i'd like to do something like this:

```
<Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="True">
    <Setter Property="{Binding IsSelected}"/>
</Trigger>
```

because a simple

```
<ListBox IsSelected="{Binding SelectedItem, Path=IsSelected, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
```

doesn't work.

I'm a bit lost here...

Answer (score 1):

I found it.

I had to set IsSelected in the style of the ListBoxItem  to make it work.